How do i load 10 objects from a mongoose array multiple times and keep the previously loaded objects?
I basically have posts with an image and title. I want to load 10 posts initially. Then when you scroll down past them you can click a 'show more posts' button to load the next 10 and be able to keep doing that. So i dont know if its exactly like pagination because its all on one page and i want to keep the previous posts loaded. Im using angular and right now my app is working with a basic 'find' request which returns all the posts.
router.get(
  "/",
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const posts = await PostModel.find().sort({ createdAt: "descending" });
    res.send(posts);
  })
);


You need to send a skip value from client in query params and your code changes like this:
router.get(
  "/",
  asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const { skip } = req.query;
    const posts = await PostModel.find().sort({ createdAt: "descending" }).skip(skip).limit(10);
    res.send(posts);
  })
);

The skip value is 0 at first request. After that increases by length of your posts. And for sorting descending you need to add some conditions to your query. Because maybe there is a new post.
